# MVC 4 - VS 2010 install unable to update NuGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I am installing **MVC 4** on a box with an up to date **VS 2010** and get **NuGet install errors**. The NuGet installed already is the newest available. I have tried installing MVC 4 with both NuGet installed already and not installed.

The error asks for **NuGet.msi**, but I have been unable to find that.

Are there any known issues that could cause this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also had problems with nuget update. This fix help us: [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Hotfix available](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=38654)

More details: [NuGet Package Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c)

`Review current release notes/known issues on the NuGet Docs site, including details and solution for about a common upgrade failure (Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Hotfix available)`

**Added:**

Also you can try to install MVC 4 with `Microsoft Web Platform Installer` after uninstalling `Nuget`.

Comment: That error is unrelated to the posters problem.  That error is when trying to upgrade to a newer version of NuGet.

Comment: I don't have to know the correct answer to know an incorrect one.